# How to generate OAuth headers for Netsuite Rest API call in Python - currently getting 401 error but it works in Postman with same env vars

Tags: python, rest, oauth, netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I need help getting a python program to authenticate against the netsuite rest api.

Firstly, I'm able to use postman to successfully call the API. I'm using Netsuite's
postman tutorial that you can download [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1545058149.html#Importing-and-Setting-Up-a-Postman-Environment)

I've successfully done all the necessary steps to create an integration application in Netsuite and get the
consumer key and secret as well as my own user token key and secret. I've put these values into
postman, along with the correct url and account id, and postman gets a 200 response back from
netsuite.

If I copy the code from postman into a python file and execute in the terminal it also works.
So my challenge is that I need to generate `timestamp`, `nonce`, and `oauth_signature`, since
these values always change each request.

The below code does all those things and forms a
proper request. I got the code from this [tutorial](https://medium.com/fsmk-engineering/a-complete-guide-to-implementing-oauth-using-python-for-netsuite-a7d34a55ab00)
One thing I should note is I didn't understand what the article mean't by "Saved Search" and
"Deployment ID". I purposely excluded this line of code because I'm not sure what it is:
`data = 'deploy=' +  + str(deployment_id) + "&"`, as well as this line: `data += 'script=' + str(script_id)`.

Lastly, when I copy the previous timestamp and nonce from postman and hard code them into my code,
the printed oauth signature is NOT the same as the one in postman. IDK why this is but I've never
been able to perfectly replicate what postman is doing.

This is my code:

```py
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import math
import os
import random
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import urllib
import requests
load_dotenv()


CONSUMER_KEY = os.getenv("CONSUMER_KEY")
CONSUMER_SECRET = os.getenv("CONSUMER_SECRET")
TOKEN_SECRET = os.getenv("TOKEN_SECRET")
TOKEN_ID = os.getenv("TOKEN_ID")
ACCOUNT_ID = os.getenv("ACCOUNT_ID")
ENDPOINT = f'{os.getenv("REST_SERVICES")}record/v1/customer/1'
SIGN_METHOD = "HMAC-SHA256"
OAUTH_VERSION = "1.0"


def getAuthNonce():
    nonce_text = ''
    length = 11
    possible= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    for i in range(length):
        nonce_text += possible[math.floor(random.uniform(0, 1) * len(possible))]
    return nonce_text


def getSignature(BASE_URL, HTTP_METHOD, OAUTH_NONCE, TIME_STAMP):
    data = 'oauth_consumer_key' + "=" + CONSUMER_KEY + "&"
    data += 'oauth_nonce' + "=" + OAUTH_NONCE + "&"
    data += 'oauth_signature_method' + "=" + SIGN_METHOD + "&"
    data += 'oauth_timestamp' + "=" + str(TIME_STAMP) + "&"
    data += 'oauth_token' + "=" + TOKEN_ID + "&"
    data += 'oauth_version' + "=" + OAUTH_VERSION + "&"
    signatureValue = HTTP_METHOD + '&' + urllib.parse.quote(BASE_URL, safe='~()*!.\'') + '&' + urllib.parse.quote(data,safe='~()*!.\'')
    signatureKey = urllib.parse.quote(CONSUMER_SECRET, safe='~()*!.\'') + '&' + urllib.parse.quote(TOKEN_SECRET,safe='~()*!.\'')
    signatureValue = bytes(signatureValue, 'utf-8')
    signatureKey = bytes(signatureKey, 'utf-8')
    shaData = hmac.new(signatureKey, signatureValue, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()

    base64EncodedData = base64.b64encode(shaData)
    oauth_signature = base64EncodedData.decode('utf-8')
    oauth_signature = urllib.parse.quote(oauth_signature, safe='~()*!.\'')
    return oauth_signature


def createHeader():
    BASE_URL = ENDPOINT
    OAUTH_NONCE = getAuthNonce()
    TIME_STAMP = round(time.time())
    HTTP_METHOD = "GET"
    oauth_signature = getSignature(BASE_URL, HTTP_METHOD, OAUTH_NONCE, TIME_STAMP)

    OAuthHeader = 'OAuth '
    OAuthHeader += 'realm="' + ACCOUNT_ID + '",'
    OAuthHeader += 'oauth_token="' + TOKEN_ID + '",'
    OAuthHeader += 'oauth_consumer_key="' + CONSUMER_KEY + '",'
    OAuthHeader += 'oauth_nonce="' + OAUTH_NONCE + '",'
    OAuthHeader += 'oauth_timestamp="' + str(TIME_STAMP) + '",'
    OAuthHeader += 'oauth_signature_method="' + SIGN_METHOD + '",'
    OAuthHeader += 'oauth_version="1.0",'
    OAuthHeader += 'oauth_signature="' + oauth_signature + '"'

    headers = {
        "Authorization": OAuthHeader,
        "prefer": "transient",
        "Cookie": "NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING"
    }
    return headers


headers = createHeader()
response = requests.request("GET", ENDPOINT, headers=headers, data={})
print(response)
print(response.text)
```

This is the error I get from my terminal

```
$ python src/try.py
<Response [401]>
{"type":"https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.2","title":"Unauthorized","status":401,"o:errorDetails":[{"detail":"Invalid login attempt. For more details, see the Login Audit Trail in the NetSuite UI at Setup > Users/Roles > User Management > View Login Audit Trail.","o:errorCode":"INVALID_LOGIN"}]}
```

And here is my postman for reference (the 404 response is a good thing because it authenticated)

[image]

Please help me to get a 200 response so I can start using this api to my advantage and I can stop
going crazy.